# Set ng-model and class property inside a directive template

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create a simple directive to make my html page abit slimmer. I want to pass down properties to the directive template and set properties.

The problem is when i am trying to pass a string and set the ng-model property and class property in the template. All the other properties i pass down work fine its just the class and ng-model property that doesnt work.
How can i set the ng-model and class property in my template by just passing down a string to them?

**controller:**

```
angular.module('app.sst').directive('inputDirective', function () {
return {
    scope: {
        colWidth: '@',
        label: '@',
        type: '@',
        name: '@',
        ngModel: '='
    },
  templateUrl: 'components/blocks/directives/inputTemplate.html',
};
});
```

**directive template:**

```
<div class="{{colWidth}}">
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <div class="field">
       <input  type="{{type}}" 
               name="{{name}}" 
               ng-model="ngModel"
               class="form-control inputText" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**index:**

```
<div input-directive 
             colWidth="col-md-4" 
             label="Proceded by" 
             type="text" 
             name="procededBy" 
             ng-model="vm.SSTItem.procededBy">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things to take note here:

1) Make ngModel required.

2) Do not use `ngModel` in isolated scope the way you are using now as angular might get confused for the key instead use meaningful name like below.

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('inputDirective', function(){
    return {
      required: '^ngModel',
      scope: {
           modelName: "=ngModel"
      },
      template: '<input type="text" ng-model="modelName">'
    };
})
```

See [**plunk**](http://plnkr.co/edit/DDVVumX0dPlk989uXhu1?p=preview).

Comment: Its not working, my ng-model is "modelName" with your suggestion.